# Best way to request/ask for fast resolution of an email

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, word-request

Their are few scenerio where i am seaching some best way to express the intention -

I heard a guy saying to his boss something like this -

> Sir, I dropped an email to IT team to format the machine and you are also in CC. Please **TOP** on this email to  get the faster resolution

in this sentence maybe I missed something near to TOP word, but I am sure he used TOP here.

Could somebody provide me the correct sentence in this scenerio.

Good explanation of scenerio and other best sentence are most welcomed and appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could somebody let me know the Use of TOP in such sentences. Is it correct or wrong. if use of  TOP is possible, could someone suggest the  correct sentences here please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommed the idiom "get right on".

> Please **get right on** this email to get it resolved faster.

[YD](http://www.yourdictionary.com/get-on-it) defines *get on it* as:

> to begin working on something or to take responsibility for working on something

[TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+right+on) notes that including the word *right* adds a sense of urgency:

> **get right on something**
>
> to do something immediately. *I know it has to be done today. I'll get right on it*.
> *Please get right on these reports as soon as possible*.

Comment: Thanks a lot J.R. for your valuable answer. Could you please also let me know that the use of TOP in the mentioned sentence is correct. if not , how it should be used here. did you hear any such sentence ,please let me know

Comment: Correct? That's hard to say. I've not heard it, but the verb _top_ could mean "to put at the top of one's priority list" – people often invent new usages of words like that. It's not always a matter of _correctness_; it could be a regionalism (if it's used in one particular area, such as Australia), or jargon (if it's used by one particular field or profession), or it could be localized slang. One place I worked would use the word "Tutch" (rhymes with "brooch") as a verb to mean _to mess up_; it was the nickname of a co-worker who had a propensity to make mistakes. :-) English is flexible.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably write something like:

> Sir, I copied you on the email to IT to format the machine.  I believe
>   this would get resolved more quickly if you were to follow up
>   with them and emphasize the urgency of the issue.

Comment: Thanks, Kelvin. i am a bit poor in grammer so i am not getting the use of'were' here. why we are using past here if action is expected in future from Boss.

Comment: This is an example of subjunctive mood, which is used in many languages to discuss unreal/hypothetical situations.  It's not just the "were" though, it's also the "if" and the "would" earlier in the sentence.  You could also rewrite it as "I believe this will get resolved more quickly if you follow up with them and emphasize the urgency of the situation." Although, to me at least, the subjunctive mood has a slightly more deferential tone which might be appropriate since you are sending it to a supervisor.